# Why is my server so slow to accept connections?

Tags: web-server, performance, connection, web, latency

I've noticed that my server seems to be very slow to accept connections - i.e. when analyzing the load time using the Chrome event map, it shows that some tasks can spend multiple seconds waiting for the server to accept a connection.  For example with the below:

- The initial page for my website (Wordpress, so I guess an index.php) spends half a second just waiting for the server to respond. (The site is http://heather.sh)

[image: Shows waiting time for the main php/main page of my website, heather.sh]

- Whilst requesting an image (700kb), Chrome is again waiting for over 5 seconds in the waiting state before it starts to receive data (at which point it finishes very quickly).  (The site is http://submarineapp.co.uk)

[image: Shows waiting time for a small image on a website hosted on this server.]

Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be going on here?  Why is my server so slow at accepting connections?  Could I have some config wrong?  It's not because of power or overload  I think - the load value rarely gets above 0.1 (it was 0.05 when I ran these tests just now), and I have plenty of available memory.  Also, the dedicated 100Mbps port is currently under less than 50kbps.  The server runs CentOS 6.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Half a second isn't bad for WordPress. But five seconds for a static image is absurd. My first suspect would be the disk it's stored on.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Are you suggesting long seek times?  I'm using Raid 1, so if there was a problem I guess the other drive would kick in if performance was lagging?  Can I ask what kind of delay you see loading that site with the background image?  I don't seem to have any problems with the drive with downloading other large files from the server (say 10mb - once it's started, it's very quick), and I don't think it's seek times as other small files are quick.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did wonder if Gzip page compression could be partly responsible?